# How can I connect flutter with php mysql with the latest version of http offline?

Tags: php, flutter, dart

i am trying to connect my flutter code with MySQL in PHP and I'm getting error when the submit button is pressed.

```
class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  String _email;
  String _pass;

  Future login(String email, String pass) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> parameters = {
      "email": _email,
      "password": _pass,
    };

    Uri uri = Uri(
      scheme: 'http',
      host: '192.168.43.107',
      path: 'flutterdb/login.php',
    );
    var body = json.encode(parameters);
    //dynamic url = "http://192.168.43.107/flutterdb/login.php";
    var response = await http.post(uri, body: body);

    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    if (data == "Error") {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Error, wrong",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Success",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
    }
  }
     //widget code
}
```

then below is my php mysqli query that i'm trying to use to validate the login after the database has been created initially

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','fireapp');

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM logintb WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password = '".$password."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_nums_rows($results);

    if($count == 1 ){
        echo json_encode('Success');
    }else{
        echo json_encode('Error');
    }


?>
```

i'm debugging with my mobile phone externally with cable....

but i'm getting this error when clicking on submit...

```
E/libPowerStretch(11572): LucidStats currentFPS = 0.09 [2395482480]
E/flutter (11572): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (11572): <br />
E/flutter (11572): ^
E/flutter (11572):
E/flutter (11572): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5)
E/flutter (11572): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1271:9)
E/flutter (11572): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:936:22)
E/flutter (11572): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
E/flutter (11572): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:506:36)
E/flutter (11572): #5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:157:41)
E/flutter (11572): #6      _SignInState.login (package:fireapp/screens/authenticate/sign_in.dart:32:21)
E/flutter (11572): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11572):
```

kindly help, i'm new to flutter....

Comment: Most often, when JSON is involved, this kind of message means that the response was not actually valid JSON. So check what your PHP script actually returned. It might for example have output some sort of PHP error message, which would surely invalidate any JSON.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Never allow your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords in plain text - that is another security risk. Learn about [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead.

Comment: Anyway it's clear that your script returned `<br />` at the start of it. Clearly that's HTML not JSON. So go find out what the full response was, then work out why that is, and fix it. Perhaps it returned an error message or something instead.

Comment: @ADyson , i didn't write any HTML those are the codes written above.

Comment: Ok so I'd guess probably PHP crashed and outputs an error message with HTML-formatting instead. Like I said you need to go and find out what actually happened.